# Probability of the input features in Boltzmann Machine

Tags: deep-learning, restricted-boltzmann-machine

On the youtube lecture at 8:15([Restricted Boltzmann machine - free energy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e0Ts_7Y6hZU&index=38&list=PL6Xpj9I5qXYEcOhn7TqghAJ6NAPrNmUBH)) professor mentioned, that we want to make the probability of the observed features to be big.

However I didn't understand from the intuitive point of view why do we want to do that? Can you explain me this idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We would like the distribution modeled by the RBM, let's call it $q(x;\theta)$ to be as similar to the true distribution $p(x)$ as possible, as measured by the KL divergence:

$$D_\text{KL}(p||q) = E_{x \sim p}[\log p(x) - \log q(x)]$$

Minimizing the KL divergence is equivalent to maximizing 
$E_{x\sim p}[\log q(x;\theta)]$, where we estimate the expectation by sampling from our dataset. This explains why we want to make the probability $q$ big.